# My Java code crashes when I try to call a method from an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I’m just learning Java and trying to have an array of a class.  When a call a methed from the array it crashes.  Works fine if it is not an array

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  cDate test=new cDate();
  test.setDay(0);
  mAppoitments = new cDate[24];
  // crashes why?????
  mAppoitments[0].setDay(0);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't filled your array with objects. You have to:

```
  cDate[0] = test;
```

Otherwise you have `null` at index 0, and you cannot invoke anything on `null`.

And next time you ask a question, give all needed details:

- what is the exception message and stacktrace. "crashes" means almost *nothing*
- tell us what are your variables that are not initialized in the code snippet. You can see one answer that is telling you to fix a local declaration, which is probably an instance variable.

Comment: HiThank you I thought the mAppoitments = new cDate[24];
 was setting it up,

Answer (score 5):

You have an array of 24 objects, each of which is set to `null`. You need to initialize each one before you can call methods on it.

Answer (score 4):

You have initialized the array but not the objects in the array. Try initializing these elements before using them.

```
mAppoitments = new cDate[24];
for (int i = 0; i < mAppoitments.length; i++)
    mAppoitments[i] = new cDate();
mAppoitments[0].setDay(0);
```

Comment: Thank youI thought mAppoitments = new cDate[24] was intializing all the objects in the array

Answer (score 1):

```
final int COUNT= 24;

mAppoitments = new cDate[COUNT];
for(int i = 0 ; i < COUNT ; ++i) {
   mAppoitments[i] = new cDate();
   mAppoitments[i].setDay(0); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cDate myAppointments = new cDate[24];
```

try declaring the variable type

Comment: If that was the problem, it wouldn't even compile. The real issue is that his array is filled with `null` references.